# Change the color of a face of a sphere geometry on hover

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting, react-three-fiber, face

Hello everyone I am a beginner in Three js what I would like to do is that when we fly over the sphere a cube is added in my scene and when the sphere is in contact with the cube, that all the faces that are inside my cube change color however I have the following error someone have an idea why please
[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu0Zt.png)

Here is my code on it
https://codesandbox.io/s/change-face-color-sphere-forked-seq87e?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

And here is the type of example I would like to have
https://hofk.de/main/discourse.threejs/2019/SelectFacesWithinRadius/SelectFacesWithinRadius.html

Comment: Please post your code or the relevant bits of it here too, don't only rely on links.

Comment: You must paste the code in the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. Also see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*